The requested resource / was not found on this server error with PHP routing
I'm trying to create a PHP project using MVC and routing, but I think my routes are not being appropriately understood by the server.
This is my routes.php:
<?php 

function load(string $controller, string $action){

    try{
        $controllerNamespace = "app\\controllers\\{$controller}";

        if(!class_exists($controllerNamespace)){
            throw new Exception("O controlador {$controller} não existe!");
        }

        $controllerInstance = new $controllerNamespace();

        if(!method_exists($controllerInstance, $action)){
            throw new Exception("O método {$action} não existe no controlador {$controller}!");
        }

        $controllerInstance->$action((object)$_REQUEST);
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    };

}

    $router = [
        'GET'=> [
            '/' => fn() => load('HomeController','index'),
            '/contact' => fn() => load('ContactController','index')
          ],
          'POST'=> [
            '/contact' => fn() => load('ContactController','store')
          ]  
    ];

    


?>

This is my index.php:
<?php
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
require "../app/routes/routes.php";

  try {
    $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
    $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    
    if (!isset($router[$request])) {
      throw new Exception("A routa não existe");
    }

    if (!array_key_exists($uri, $router[$request])) {
      throw new Exception("A routa não existe");
    }

    $controller = $router[$request][$uri];
    $controller();

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
  }

?>

This is my ContactController.php:
<?php 


    namespace app\Controller;

    class ContactController{
        public function index(){
            return Controller::view('contact');
        }

        public function store($params){
            var_dump($params->nome);
        }
    }


?>

And this is my composer.json:
{
    "name": "pedroneto/teste_roteamento",
    "description": "estudos de rotas em PHP",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "app\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "league/plates": "^3.5"
    }
}

This is the repository, if anyone wants to see the project structure: https://github.com/pedronet00/teste_roteamento
I've tried to use the XAMPP server, but it did not work out as well. I'm using php -S localhost:3000 to run the project. I'm not getting any errors from the Exceptions, because the routes are not working.
This is the error print:

Please write the exact meaning of "it did not work out as well". what's happening. Are you getting a specific error? or the routing doesn't work in some conditions?

Please clarify - are you getting the English error message you put into the question title, or any of the Portuguese errors from your own code?

"This is the repository, if anyone wants to see the project structure:" - we want to see relevant code here, not in external repositories. What you have shown here so far, is only configuration. Where & what you do with those settings, is currently missing.

Well, it looks like your generated composer autoload files might not be setup correctly. Seeing in your vendor/composer/autoload_static.php and vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php the app namespace is not present at all. Try running composer dump-autoload in the root of the project, where composer.json is placed. That should refresh the autoload files.
